# Java error Could not find or load main class package

Tags: java, class, command-line, io, package

When I run this code from eclips it will give the error print:

```
package Chapter08_JavaIOFundamentals;
import java.io.Console;

public class Echo {
     public static void main(String []args) {
          Console console = System.console();
          if(console == null) {
              System.err.println("Cannot retrive console object - are you running your application from an IDE? Exiting the application ... ");
          ystem.exit(-1); }
     console.printf(console.readLine());
     }
 }
```

But when i try to run it from a command line like this.

```
javac Echo.java //(this will gives no errors)
java Echo
```

it will give a error:
Error: Could not find or load main class Echo.
Other programma's like Hello World give no problem. 
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call `java -cp . Chapter08_JavaIOFundamentals.Echo` from the parent directionry of `Chapter08_JavaIOFundamentals`

Comment: C:\Users\martijn_habraken\workspace\ocpjp 7 source code\src>java Chapter08_JavaIOFundamentals.Echo
Error: Could not find or load main class Chapter08_JavaIOFundamentals.Echo

Comment: Is your class file in `src/...`?

Comment: Yes, it is.
When i run it like this it is not giving the error annymore thanks.

Comment: I have changed my answer. Can you try t again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that you added the location of your `.class` file to your classpath. If it is in the current folder then you can a `dot .` in your classpath

Comment: I don't have a class path in my env.variables

Comment: Try this: `java -cp path/of/your/class Echo and then java -cp . Echo`